# How to calculate the height of a prism when the perimeter is given?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

The problem is as follows:

> For the architecture class Joan and Peter must each make a **right**
>   **regular prism** of equal volume. Joan built a triangular prism and Peter
>   constructed a quadrangular prism whose height is $12\sqrt{3}$ inches.
>   If their bases from both prisms have the same perimeter. How tall is
>   the prism Joan built?

Apparently the problem lies in the interpretation of the word "regular prism" by looking on [this source](http://www.mathwords.com/r/regular_prism.htm), a *regular prism* is a prism with bases that are *regular polygons* with the latter meaning from [this other source](http://www.mathwords.com/r/regular_polygon.htm) being a polygon for which all sides are congruent and all angles are congruent. In other words, for this problem would meant that the base of $\textrm{Prism A}$ is a equilateral triangle and $\textrm{Prism B}$ is a square.

From the previous information I made a sketch of how I thought to solve the problem.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

Prism $\textrm{A}: a=b=c$ and $\textrm{Prism B: e=f}$. Hence reducing the formulas for area and volume to this:

$$V_{1}=h_{1} \times \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-a)(s-a)}$$
$$V_{2}=12\sqrt{3}\times e\times e$$

then:

$$3a=4e$$

Therefore both volumes are the same,

$$h_{1} \times \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-a)(s-a)}=12\sqrt{3}\times e^{2}$$

$$h_{1} \times \sqrt{\frac{3a}{2}(\frac{3a}{2}-a)^{3}}=12\sqrt{3}\times e^{2}$$

$$h_{1} \times \sqrt{\frac{3a}{2}(\frac{a}{2})^{3}}=12\sqrt{3}\times e^{2}$$

$$h_{1} \times \sqrt{\frac{3a^{4}}{2^{4}}}=12\sqrt{3}\times e^{2}$$

$$h_{1} \times \frac{a^{2}}{4}\sqrt{3}=12\sqrt{3}\times e^{2}$$

Replacing the $\textrm{e}$ by $e=\frac{3a}{4}$

$$h_{1} \times \frac{a^{2}}{4}\sqrt{3}=12\sqrt{3}\times \frac{3^{2}a^{2}}{4^{2}}$$

$$h_{1} = \frac{12\times 3^{2}}{4}$$

$$h_{1} = 27$$

Therefore the result would become into $\textrm{27 inches}$. By following this way of writing Heron's formula:

$$A=\frac{1}{4}\times \sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}$$

I got the same result.

Overall, does the method I used is right?.

Comment: It seem that we need some other given, for the triangle indeed for a same perimeter we can have different area for the base (see Eron formula) and dofferent hieghts, or am I wrong?

Comment: @gimusi There will be different areas and heights. But I could be naive and just think that $12\sqrt{3}$ would be the height. But we cannot prove that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough information to answer the question.  The heights have to be in inverse ratio to the area of the bases.  The area of Prism B has area $ef$ and perimeter $2e+2f$.  You are given that $a+b+c=2e+2f$ to make the perimeters equal, but the area of the triangular base can be anything from $0$ up to $\frac {\sqrt 3}{36}(2e+2f)^2$

Comment: As you mentioned i'm adding the missing information. I also noticed it. However can you tell me how did you got to $\frac{\sqrt{3}(2e+2f)^{2}}{36}$?

Comment: I got it by deriving the area of an equilateral triangle given its perimeter.  If the perimeter is $p$, the side is $\frac p3$, the altitude is $\frac {\sqrt 3}6p$